# Cannot get the basics of a method call working?

Tags: java

As silly as this sounds, this is stumping me considering i've been a CompSci Undergrad for 2 years now; Pretty Much I have a minesweeper game than automatically adds the username and time to a leaderboard(this is the goal).

But for the life of me I cannot get what is going wrong:

```
private LeaderBoard m_leaderBoard;
```

Here is the method that calls the "addToLeaderBoard".

```
public boolean setGameWin() {
    try {
        System.out.println("output");
        m_won.loop(1);
        m_time.stop();
        m_tick.stop();
        m_GameFinshed.setVisible(true);
        m_GameFinshed.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/GameWon.jpg"));

        String v = "You Have won\n time taken- " + m_timePassed;
        m_leaderBoard.addToLeaderBoard(m_player.getUsername(), m_timePassed);
        // ^^ Exception is raised here

        return true;
    } catch (Exception x) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and the method int he leaderBoard Class is this:

```
public void addToLeaderBoard(String m_username, String m_timePassed) {
    System.out.println(m_username +  m_timePassed);

}
```

but it does not print out the username or time passed, I have absolutely not idea why.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at game.GameController.setGameWin(GameController.java:214)
at game.GameController.mouseClicked(GameController.java:289)
```

exception that is printed

Comment: Are you sure you have no raised `Exception` in `setGameWin` ?

Comment: Does the `leaderBoard` class have any subclasses which override the method?

Comment: @Berger you got it BUT everything updates as it should such as the .setIcon(new ImageIcon(...)).

Comment: Check your values of m_player.getUsername() and m_timePassed. And you're throwing away exceptions at the moment. You could check the value returned by setGameWin and if it's false, then you'll know you've definitely encountered an exception. But the way it works right now,  you're not necessarily handling that scenario. I wouldn't recommend simply returning true or false on the basis of any exception being raised. And you could drop the "m_" prefix on your variables. That's not in line with Java coding standards.

Comment: When all else fails, step through the method in a debugger.  That can show what is happening.  (I agree with the others: you probably have an exception being thrown, but since you didn't log it anywhere you simply don't know at this time)

Comment: `"it does not print out the username or time passed"` - Then what *does* it do?  When you step through this in a debugger, where/how *specifically* does it fail?

Comment: @PigeonMilk Stories , so the problem arises after the `setIcon` instruction, the `addToLeaderBoard` line crashes. As suggested above, it may be a problem of a `null` object, what is the Exception ?

Comment: my bet: m_leaderBoard is null and in catch you should at least add `x.printStacktrace();`

Comment: Yep, m_leaderboard or m_player could be null and it falls at that point.

Comment: Blindly swallowing `Exception` instances like this is a very bad idea. If an exception occurs, you pretty much always want to have some indication that it has occurred (e.g. print the stack trace, at a minimum; better to propagate the exception to the caller).

Comment: I'm not sure if this will notify you but this isn't "my"code, the return false on the excepction is not my doing :)

Comment: @PigeonMilkStories well, tell them that it's a very bad idea, and that it wasted your time in trying to work out why the code was failing.

Comment: The exception tells you the line of the error. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create an Instance of LeaderBoard

```
m_leaderBoard = new LeaderBoard()
```

try to add a log after the catch and see what is doing

Comment: This sorted my issue out but obviously there is a bigger issue at hand  :)

Answer (score 0):

If `m_leaderBoard` is null, `m_player` is `null`, or `m_player.getUserName()` throws an exception, then your icon will be updated, but `m_leaderBoard.addToLeaderBoard()` won't be called.

You should walk through your code line-by-line with a debugger to watch what happens.

You should also not drop exceptions in your `catch` block - use `x.printStackTrace()` at the very least.